# Set a notification to have changing Trigger.Execution values

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a created a notification that is scheduled through a Firebase `JobService` and currently the notification sends every minute forever.

How do I make it so that the first time the notification takes 5 minutes to appear, then after that it sends every 30 seconds for, lets say, 20 minutes?

Comment: Hey, you should try something by yourself before posting questions here. Please come back when you will have some "research effort" to show us, or in the best case you will solve the problem by yourself!

Comment: What external or internal trigger are you using to trigger the notification? Is it triggered from  your App or an external CRON job.